# Не работает бургер бутстрап 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Появляется бургег при клике не открывается меню. Делал по документации бутстрапа. В чем проблема не могу понять.

(Bootstrap 4)

Подключение bootstrap

header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

body

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js " integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
```

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: #03519A;">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" style="background-color: white;" type="button " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#navbarSupportedContent " aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent " aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center " id="navbarSupportedContent ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">АНКЕТЫ МАСТЕРОВ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">НАШИ УСЛУГИ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">ПОМОЩЬ В ДОРОГЕ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">БЛОГ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link " href="# ">ПРОГРАММА ЛОЯЛЬНОСТИ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: У Вас просто куча каких-то лишних пробелов в классах, дата-атрибутах и т.д. Поправьте вёрстку, и всё заработает

Comment: Эти пробелы ставит визуал студия код. После сохранения, она форматирует код.

Comment: @Daniil По названиям классов бутстрап как раз таки и понимает, что ему нужно работать именно с этим DOM элеменом. Попробуйте настроить форматирование кода, чтобы небыло таких пробем

Comment: @Daniil, я Вам объяснил, в чём проблема. Как уж Вы будете её решать, Ваше дело. Но пробелов быть не должно.

Comment: Проблема решена. Действительно пробел.